# Value Labels not updating Data in SPSS

Tags: spss, stat

I'm working with diagnostic questionnaire questions in SPSS to identify if an individual is depressed. I have imported the data from the survey and changed the the value labels to reflect the score weighting from each answer.

So it has gone from this

[image: Before]

To this

[image: After]

However when i use compute variable to add these scores up the the scores are not reflecting the change. The range of scores should be 0 to 60. However the range Im getting is 20-80. Through observation it seems like that data(shown in data view) is still going from 1-4 which is the reason for the higher scores. Is there anyway to address this? I am fairly new to SPSS, so i apologise if my question is a basic one.

P.S: i am also aware that i have to compute variable each time i change the value labels.

Comment: The value labels are separate "meta data" on top of the values that are actually encoded into the data.  From what you have above, it looks like you want to COMPUTE myvar = myvar - 1.  EXECUTE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @KevinTroy says, changing the **value labels** will not change the **values**.
To complete the job and change the values too you can use `recode` or `compute`:

```
recode YourVar (1=0)(2=1)(3=2)(4=3).
```

Or @KevinTroy's method:

```
compute YourVar = YourVar - 1.
```

To see that you did what you intended, take a look at the data before and after running either of these two lines, to see that the numbers change as expected.